# Silverlight auto height problems with nested controls

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, accordion

I've inherited a silverlight app that now needs extending. The app sits on a map and originally had 1 text block item and a single accordion control of options. This has been extended so that the text block becomes an accordion item and further accordion item has been added with 2 sets of controls.

So my plan started along the lines of

```
<accordionMain>
  <accordionMainItem1>
    <accordion1>
      <accordion1Item>
        <controls>
      </accordion1Item>
      <accordion1Item2>
        <controls>
      </accordion1Item2>
    </accordion1>
  <accordionMainItem1>
  <accordionMainItem2>
    <accordion2>
      <accordion2Item>
        <controls>
      </accordion2Item>
      <accordion2Item2>
        <controls>
      </accordion2Item2>
    </accordion2>
  <accordionMainItem2>
</accordionMain>
```

This would hopefully give me the structure that I needed to add controls to.

Being new to Silverlight but having done a bit of XAML I made some progress but have hit a problem.

The StackPanel and Canvas that the whole thing sits on does not resize automatically as I would like. I'm unsure how to go about this but have tried Height="Auto" with no luck. What I would like would be when the 2nd accordion is expanded the panel and border underneath auto size as needed.

I have attached the [full XAML here](http://1drv.ms/1oMPHIE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I avoid the `StackPanel` for non-trivial layout of controls. I find a `Grid` is much more flexible when it comes to filling available space and resizing, which is normally what I want when designing an interface that will grow and shrink.

So my first step with your example would be to define a couple of rows for your grid, and place your expanding elements into a row each. Looking back at your example I see there is actually only one expanding thing: the `AccordianMain`, so make sure that is in a `Row` where `Height="Auto"`.

What are you using the `Canvas` for incidentally? And why is the `Grid` that contains the accordians on the `Canvas`, and the only item in the `StackPanel` the `Canvas`?

Try and simplify your layout, I don't see why your inner `Grid` can't be directly placed into your `Border` and so can't see what the `StackPanel` or `Canvas` are bringing to the party. But maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. You're not missing anything - I copied the existing bunch of controls and wrapped them in an AccordionItem of the main accordion. My intention was to then remove the 'extra' control I didn't need. In doing that I also copied all of the canvas and stack panels those controls were sitting on. I'm currently removing them to simplify matters.

Comment: I think removing the `Canvas` will solve your problems. The Canvas uses absolute positioning, which doesn't take into account resizing. In nearly all cases you can get a nice dynamic size layout just from clever use of the `Grid`.

Comment: Your suggestion about removing the canvas was spot on. I also applied the style fix here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680985/how-to-get-accordion-region-to-expand-vertically-to-dynamic-content and that fixed an issue with the nested accordions not drawing properly. Many thanks.